# Dependency conflict between pandas and openpyxl did not show up while trying to install packages

Tags: pandas, pip, python-packaging

I am working on a Python service ( running with Python 3.10 ) where I am installing all the dependencies using `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Normally this throws an error as follows if there's a dependency confict between the files.

For example, if I am using these  packages,python-datetutil (2.8.1), botocore (1.16.2) and pandas (2.0.0), it throws the below error

```
ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 3), pandas==2.0.0 and python-dateutil==2.8.1 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
The conflict is caused by:
The user requested python-dateutil==2.8.1
botocore 1.16.2 depends on python-dateutil<3.0.0 and >=2.1
pandas 2.0.0 depends on python-dateutil>=2.8.2
To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
```

However, it does not throw any error if there's a package support issue. For example, if I am using the package `openpyxl ( 3.0.6 )` and `pandas ( 2.0.0 )`, the part of the code where `openpyxl` is used will throw the following error

`Pandas require version '3.0.7' or newer of 'openpyxl' (version '3.0.6' is currently installed)`.

But this we get only when we run that part of the code.

Why is this error not shown while installing the package?
Is there any other command that can be used to identify all such issues?

Comment: Openpyxl doesn't have this dependency

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is this error not shown while installing the package?

Because your `requirements.txt` file only contains `pandas==2.0.0` and `openpyxl` is an optional dependency in the group `excel`.

Check the [`pandas/pyproject.toml`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.0.0/pyproject.toml):

```
excel = ['odfpy>=1.4.1', 'openpyxl>=3.0.7', 'pyxlsb>=1.0.8', 'xlrd>=2.0.1', 'xlsxwriter>=1.4.3']
```

If you modify your `requirements.txt` like this:

```
openpyxl==3.0.6
pandas[excel]==2.0.0
```

The command `pip install -r requirements.txt` will failed:

```
ERROR: Cannot install openpyxl==3.0.6 and pandas[excel]==2.0.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested openpyxl==3.0.6
    pandas[excel] 2.0.0 depends on openpyxl>=3.0.7; extra == "excel"

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
```

Solution, remove `openpyxl` from `requirements.txt` and let `pip` manage the correct version.